# CSS: How to not let the join now box disappear when width is smaller

Tags: html, css

I've tried setting width at `max-width: 786px` to `container` but it doesn't seem to affect it properly, but affects other elements as well.

```
@media (max-width : 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 768px;
        padding-top: 200px;
    }
}
```

How can I move the text container "David Kim ... people over profits" down @ 967 width (so it doesn't cover his face) & not allow the email join box disappear @ 767 width?

The site is at: https://davidkim.socialarts.com

Thanks so much in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have this happening at 767px so why not alter that code to be 967?

```
@media (max-width: 967px) {
  .tt-content-wrapper .tt-intro-sub {
    padding-top: 433px;
  }
}
```

This is the code that is removing the join now box:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .banner-joinnow-form {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Simply update this to width that you want it to disappear at.